# A way to migrate existing reports from Qlikview to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, qlikview

I have reports to migrate from Qlikview to Power Bi desktop.
I wonder if there is a tool (API) or an approach to do the migration.
Or the only solution to do that is to rebuild everything in Power BI ?

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if there were such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with both products for several years. The technologies are very different. However, you can export the data from QlikView and read the data into Power BI. Then you will actually be able to transfer the model and the data. The user Interface must be created from scratch.

As always in data science 80% of the work is in the data model.  By following this procedure you will be able to migrate the most important part of your solution.